# How can i position a logo image from a list react component?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styling

i would like to find the way to position the logo images like it looks here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOXgl.jpg)

I couldn`t find a way to position multiple logo images, out of the container of each card, i also have tried absolute positioning but it keeps related to the viewport and not to the card. Moreover, i tried to use pseudoelements, but i couldn't pass the url dynamically into the pseudoelement.

Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), when using `position: absolute`, "it is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor".

A positioned ancestor is simply an element that also has `position` defined as something other than `static`. If none of your image's ancestors are positioned, then it will be positioned relative to the viewport.

The common approach is therefore to use `position: relative` on an ancestor of your image (in your case, probably on the card element).

```css
body {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 5rem;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1rem;
  left: 0.5rem;
  
  background: blue;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```